# problems with c++ set container

Tags: c++, stl, set

When I try to compile the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <set>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    template <class T, class S> 
    class Property
    {
    public:
        pair<T,S> p;

        Property(T t, S s) { p = make_pair(t,s);}

    };

    int main()
    {
    set< Property<string, string> > properties;
    Property<string, string> name("name", "Andy");

    properties.insert(name);

    }
```

I get the compilation error.
However, when I replace set by vector and hence use the the push_back function instead of insert function everything works fine. Could anyone explain me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advice.

Comment: You might want to try `std::unordered_set` if you don't care about the ordering, which you don't seem to here, judging by the error you get, which I've magically deciphered from compiling this in my brain.

Comment: @chris it'd probably be more work to use `std::unordered_set` since you have to provide a hash and equality operator.

Comment: @Rapptz, True, though ordering doesn't seem to me like it would be prominent here.

Comment: Without defining ordering (`operator <(const Property&)`, the standard `std::set` has no way of determining identity of an element (which, btw, is done with `(!(left < right) && !(right < left))`, so make sure your order is consistent). The `std::pair<>` template defines the most commonly used order comparator already, so unless you have a specific reason *not* to, you could well easily solve your issue by simply throwing out `Property` as a formal definition and instead just using `typedef std::pair<string,string> Property;` I'm guessing, however, you need case-insensitive label comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) stores its values in a sorted binary tree, so it needs to know how to compare the values it holds. By default it uses [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) as a comparison function, which for un-specialized user defined types tries to call `operator<`. So, the easiest way to tell the set how to compare your objects is to define an `operator<` for your class:

```
template <class T, class S> 
class Property
{
public:
    pair<T,S> p;

    Property(T t, S s) { p = make_pair(t,s);}

    bool operator<(const Property<T,S>& rhs) const
    {
        return p < rhs.p;
    }
};
```

However, there are also other ways of telling `std::set` how to compare your type. One is to specialize the `std::less` template for your class:

```
namespace std {
template<typename T,typename S>
struct less<Property<T, S> >
{
    bool operator()(const Property<T, S>& lhs, const Property<T,S>& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.p < rhs.p;
    }
};
}
```

Another is to replace the default comparison type with a function with the correct signature, or a class that has an `operator()` defined with the correct signature. This is where things start to get ugly.

```
// Comparison function
template<typename T, typename S>
bool property_less_function(const Property<T,S>& lhs, const Property<T,S>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.p < rhs.p;
}

// Comparison functor
template<typename T, typename S>
struct PropertyLess
{
    bool operator()(const Property<T,S>& lhs, const Property<T,S>& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.p < rhs.p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Set using comparison function. 
    // Have to pass the function pointer in the constructor so it knows
    // which function to call. The syntax could be cleaned up with some
    // typedefs.
    std::set<Property<std::string, std::string>, 
        bool(*)(const Property<std::string, std::string>&, 
                const Property<std::string, std::string>&)> 
            set1(&property_less_function<std::string, std::string>);

    // Set using comparison functor. Don't have to pass a value for the functor
    // because it will be default constructed.
    std::set<Property<std::string, std::string>, PropertyLess<std::string, std::string> > set2;
}
```

Keep in mind that whatever less-than function you use, that function must define a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) for your type.

Comment: I'd move the template from `PropertyLess` to it's `operator()`, that way you don't have to duplicate the parameters `std::set<Property<std::string, std::string>, PropertyLess> set3;`

Answer (score 2):

In order to insert something into `std::set`, you need to have `operator<` defined.

For example this compiles fine on GCC 4.7.2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T, class S> 
class Property
{
public:
    pair<T,S> p;
    Property(T t, S s) { 
        p = make_pair(t,s);
    }
    bool operator<(const Property& p2) const {
        //Something naive..
        return p < p2.p; 
    }

};

int main()
{
set< Property<string, string> > properties;
Property<string, string> name("name", "Andy");

properties.insert(name);

}
```

An alternative would be to use `std::unordered_set` though that would require you to provide a hash for the key and defining `operator==`.

Comment: Your implementation of operator< does not give a strict weak order, so it will cause problems at runtime.  Just use pair's operator< to directly compare the stored pairs.

Comment: You don't _need_ `operator<`, you could also provide a comparitor.