# Cocos2d deleting b2Bodies

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, collision-detection, contacts

I have been trying to get collision detection working in cocos2d using the Ray Wenderlich tutorials but whenever I try to destroy the b2Body I get `inline b2Body* b2Fixture::GetBody() { return m_body; }` whenever the objects collide. I've looked at similar questions but none of them seem to work for me. Here is my tick method; the problem begins at "std::vector", the code before it runs fine, just detecting the collision between the two bodies and destroying both b2Bodies gives me an error every time:
`

```
(void)tick:(ccTime) dt {
    _world->Step(dt, 10, 10);
    ...some code that works fine...then here when trying to delete the bodies:
    std::set<b2Body *>toDestroy;
std::set<MyContact>::iterator pos;
for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin();
    pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) {
    MyContact contact = *pos;
    bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
    bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
    if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL) {
        spriteA = (__bridge CCSprite *) bodyA->GetUserData();
        spriteB = (__bridge CCSprite *) bodyB->GetUserData();
            if (((spriteA.tag == 411 || spriteA.tag == 412) && spriteB.tag == 8))
            {
                //Remove CCSprites
                [self removeBall];
                for(CCSprite *tile4 in row4){
                    [self removeTiles];
                    [row4 removeObject:tile4];
                    [childrenToDestroy addObject:tile4];
                }

                //Remove b2bodies by adding them to array
                toDestroy.insert(bodyA);
                toDestroy.insert(bodyB);
            }
    }
}
std::set<b2Body *>::iterator pos2;
for(pos2 = toDestroy.begin(); pos2 != toDestroy.end(); ++pos2) {
    b2Body *body = *pos2;
    if (body->GetUserData() != NULL)
    {
        body->SetActive(false);
        _world->DestroyBody(body);
    }
}
```

This part of the code looks right but then I get an error in a boilerplate file "**stl_function.h" saying "Invalid operands to binary expression ('const MyContact' and 'const MyContact')**" and It says it's found in my contact listener file:

```
#import "MyContactListener.h"

MyContactListener::MyContactListener() : _contacts() {
}

MyContactListener::~MyContactListener() {
}

void MyContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) {
MyContact myContact = { contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB() };
_contacts.insert(myContact);  <------------//Says "7.In instantiation of member function 'std::set<MyContact, std::less<MyContact>, std::allocator<MyContact> >::insert' requested here"
}

void MyContactListener::EndContact(b2Contact* contact) {
MyContact myContact = { contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB() };
std::set<MyContact>::iterator pos;
pos = std::find(_contacts.begin(), _contacts.end(), myContact);
if (pos != _contacts.end()) {
    _contacts.erase(pos);
}
}

void MyContactListener::PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold) {
}

void MyContactListener::PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse* impulse) {
}
```

Comment: The loop in removeBodies at the end there may be trying to destroy the same body twice. Try using a std::set instead of a std::vector for the toDestroy container, to prevent putting duplicates in it.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed all places where i've had vector to set, and changed push_back to insert and I think I almost have it. However, I am getting an error in my contact listener now that I have never seen before. I've added the code above.

Comment: I don't think you needed to change all vectors to sets, just the 'toDestroy' one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove bodies only between two steps. Collision callbacks are called during time step, so you should remember somehow bodies to remove (for example, add to global array), and then at next step destroy them. More detail [there](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/removing-bodies).

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the std::set, your element will be stored by a key (like a map).  So you need to define the < operator.  [Look for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784620/problems-with-c-set-container)

Something like:

```
struct Data
{
   int x;
   int y;

   bool operator<(const Data& rhs) const
   {
      return x < rhs.x;
   }

};

void InsertData(const Data& data)
{
   std::set<Data> dataSet;

   dataSet.insert(data);
}
```

I found that the contact listener gives multiple "hits" on the same bodies during collision resolution.  This led to several problems since entities were getting notified about collisions multiple times, they were destroyed multiple times, sleep was lost, etc.

I wrote a contact listener (below) that automatically checked for duplicates and excluded them.  This works as expected:

```
class EntityContactListener : public ContactListener
{
private:
   GameWorld* _gameWorld;
   EntityContactListener() {}

   typedef struct 
   {
      Entity* entA;
      Entity* entB;
   } CONTACT_PAIR_T;

   vector<CONTACT_PAIR_T> _contactPairs;

public:
   virtual ~EntityContactListener() {}

   EntityContactListener(GameWorld* gameWorld) :
      _gameWorld(gameWorld)
   {
      _contactPairs.reserve(128);
   }

   void NotifyCollisions()
   {
      Message* msg;
      MessageManager& mm = GameManager::Instance().GetMessageMgr();

      for(uint32 idx = 0; idx < _contactPairs.size(); idx++)
      {
         Entity* entA = _contactPairs[idx].entA;
         Entity* entB = _contactPairs[idx].entB;

         //DebugLogCPP("Contact Notification %s<->%s",entA->ToString().c_str(),entB->ToString().c_str());

         msg = mm.CreateMessage();
         msg->Init(entA->GetID(), entB->GetID(), Message::MESSAGE_COLLISION);
         mm.EnqueueMessge(msg, 0);

         msg = mm.CreateMessage();
         msg->Init(entB->GetID(), entA->GetID(), Message::MESSAGE_COLLISION);
         mm.EnqueueMessge(msg, 0);         
      }
      _contactPairs.clear();
   }

   void PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold)
   {

   }

   // BEWARE:  You may get multiple calls for the same event.
   void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
   {
      Entity* entA = (Entity*)contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
      Entity* entB = (Entity*)contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
      //DebugLogCPP("Begin Contact %s->%s",entA->ToString().c_str(),entB->ToString().c_str());
      if(entA->GetGroupID() == entB->GetGroupID())
      {  // Can't collide if they are in the same group.
         return;
      }

      assert(entA != NULL);
      assert(entB != NULL);

      for(uint32 idx = 0; idx < _contactPairs.size(); idx++)
      {
         if(_contactPairs[idx].entA == entA && _contactPairs[idx].entB == entB)
            return;
         // Not sure if this is needed...
         if(_contactPairs[idx].entA == entB && _contactPairs[idx].entA == entB)
            return;
      }
      CONTACT_PAIR_T pair;
      pair.entA = entA;
      pair.entB = entB;
      _contactPairs.push_back(pair);
   }

   // BEWARE:  You may get multiple calls for the same event.
   void EndContact(b2Contact* contact)
   {
      /*
      Entity* entA = (Entity*)contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
      Entity* entB = (Entity*)contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
      DebugLogCPP("End Contact %s->%s",entA->ToString().c_str(),entB->ToString().c_str());
       */
   }
};
```

In this code base, there was a "MessageManager" that received messages that got called after the physics and would process the collision messages, passing them to the entities.  You can modify the NotifyCollisions code to your destruction if you wish.

Was this helpful?